# Why is my Login Activity giving me a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

If I use the correct login it works fine but When I try to test it with fake  login details it doesnt diplay the error message. It just crashes instead.

Here's the code

```
       public void onClick(View view) {
           String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
           String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
           UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
           JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            //check for login response
           try {
               if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                   loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                   String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                   if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        //user successfully logged in
                        //Store user details in SQLite Database
                       DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                       JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                       // Clear all previous data in database
                       userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                       db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        //Launch Dashboard Screen
                       Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        //Close all views before launching Dashboard
                       dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                       startActivity(dashboard);

                        //Close Login Screen
                       finish();
                   }else{
                        //Error in login
                       loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                   }
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });
```

Here 's the logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at your.dissertation.project.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 62 of LoginActivity.java? That's where you're getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: I noticed this but couldn't find anything wrong with the line its the `  if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)` line

Comment: Your `json` object is likely null then :)

Comment: The obvious conclusion here is that the JSON object must have been null to begin with. Try checking for that.

Comment: Yes JSON returned null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure you `json` object is not null after making the `JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);` call.

Comment: Yep its null, why is this?

Comment: You'll need to post the content of `userFunction.loginUser(email, password);`

Comment: its okay just found out the database i'm accessing is down... can't even login now.. so ye. Thanks

Comment: @user2268970 haha, nice. Glad you figured out the issue.